Error nbformat when uploading to github from google colab
When trying to save a copy of my Google Colab notebook to GitHub repository ,I'm getting this error:

Using nbformat v5.10.4 and nbconvert v7.16.1.

It would be great if someone could please help.
I tried to change the nbformat and nbformat_minor to 4 and 5 respectively but I couldn't resolve the issue.
